# SQL select when one condition or another are met but not both

Tags: sql, select

Given the following table:

```
id      column1   column2
-------------------------
1       3         8
2       4         7
3       4         10
4       4         14
5       14        17
6       10        27
7       14        21
8       16        14
9       21        4
10      30        3
```

what is the nicest way to query selecting rows when number 4 and 14 are selected in `column1` or `column2` BUT exclude when number 4 and number 14 are both in the row. Be aware that the order can be reversed.

expected output

```
id      column1   column2
-------------------------
2       4         7
3       4         10
5       14        17
7       14        21
8       16        14
9       21        4
```

Comment: What happens if `column1` and `column2` hold the same value of either 4 or 14? Also, what database?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1=4 XOR column2=14) XOR (column1=14 XOR column2=4)
```

Comment: nice one. And looking the answer it seems that this was a good question indeed

Comment: Simple solution and I don't mean to detract from that, but I'm not sure I'd consider it appropriate given that no database platform was specified. This won't work on Oracle for example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE ((column1 = 4 AND column2 != 14)
OR    (column2 = 14 AND column1 != 4)
OR    (column1 = 14 AND column2 != 4)
OR    (column2 = 4 AND column1 != 14))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, column1, column2
FROM table
WHERE column1 in ('4','14') AND column2 NOT IN ('4','14')
OR column2 in ('4','14') AND column1 NOT IN ('4','14')
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's the nicest way, but this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (
    column1 IN (4,14)
        AND
    column2 NOT IN (4,14)
) OR (
    column1 NOT IN (4,14)
        AND
    column2 IN (4,14)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as(
    SELECT * FROM t WHERE column1 in(4,14) or column2 in(4,14)
)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE (column1 in(4,14) or column2 in(4,14)) and id not in(select id from cte where column1 in(4,14) and column2 in(4,14))
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM t WHERE column1 in(4,14) or column2 in(4,14)
except
SELECT * FROM t WHERE column1 in(4,14) and column2 in(4,14)

Answer (score 0):

select * from table
where (column1=4 or column2=14) and not (column1=4 and column2=14);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).